Hiding delivery methods without price in the basket | Woccommerce | WCFM Marketplace
I'm new and looking for help.
I want to hide delivery methods in my cart that do not have a price listed.
function ts_hide_shipping_without_prices( $rates ) {
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        // Check if the cost is zero and the method is not free
        if ( 0 == $rate->cost && 'free_shipping' !== $rate->method_id ) {
            unset( $rates[ $rate_id ] );
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'ts_hide_shipping_without_prices', 100 );

I have the code below, but it also hides Free Shipping because it also has no price. I don't want it!
I want the code below to bypass Free Shipping. Free shipping is supposed to be displayed always.

As you are using 'free_shipping' !== $rate->method_id in your IF statement, your current code is not hiding the Free Shipping method, so the issue comes from somewhere else, like in the Free Shipping settings where you may have a minimum order amount defined…

@loictheaztek We are a marketplace. Many of my Vendors have their own shipping policies. Each of them also has its own Free Shipping depending on the price. Could this be a problem?
Below is the Free Shipping HTML/CSS code for one of my Vendors.



As your code is targeting all Free Shipping methods (free_shipping), but not a specific Free Shipping method rate ID like free_shipping:19, your code should work. So may be the issue comes from WCFM plugin, which may need a specific dedicated hook… In that case, you should search and ask in WCFM plugin support threads. You can always try to increase the hook priority from 100 to 1000000…
